# RegEx for matching only digits and a maximum of 3 characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Can someone give me a hint why the following RegEx doesn’t work? I‘m trying to validate a string that must  contain at least one number 0-9 at the beginning or the end and maximum 3 characters (A-Z) and including whitespaces. I‘ve tried:

```
^[0-9]{1,}\s*\w{0,3}|\w{0,3}\s*[0-9]{1,}
```

But the RegEx above matches everything that contains those characters. But I want to make sure that it matches only if no more than desired characters and numbers are in my string.

Should return true:

- 9 aaa
- 99244 aaa
- ABC 321
- 9A

Should return false:

- 9999 fjejdhshsh dud
- 9 Dudu du
- Hdjdjso djs 99

I‘d really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: Try like [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aaNz3S/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things:

- You are only anchoring `^` the first alternative.
- And you probably should be using `$` as well, if you want to assert the whole string.
- Else the second `|\w{0,3}\s*` alternative might match *anywhere* (and would also match an empty string really)
- Furthermore, make this more readable with `\d+` instead of `[0-9]{1,}`
- But more strict for `[A-Z][0,3}` instead of `\w` (might match numbers).

So in essence:

```
/^(
     \d+ \s* [A-Z]{0,3}    # 123 ABC
  |
     [A-Z]{0,3} \s* \d+    # ABC 123
  )$
/ix   # /x flag for readability
```

Comment: Thanks Mario, you saved me hours. My final version is this one: /(^\d+\s*[A-Za-z]{0,2}|^[A-Za-z]{0,2}\s*\d+)$/uisx